# External geojson not showing in OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I'm new to OpenLayers. I tried some recipes found here to load an external geojson file as an overlay on a map I'm creating and it's not working. The map as well as my base layer are loading, but no overlay...

Can anyone help?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var map;

    function init() {


        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {numZoomLevels:20,
                                                projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                                                }           
                                );

        var mblight = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
            'Mapbox light',
            "https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/amt-isam.h1ec7ila/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", 
            {
            attribution: "Tiles &copy; <a href='http://mapbox.com/'>MapBox</a> | " + 
            "Data &copy; <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/'>OpenStreetMap</a> " +
            "and contributors, CC-BY-SA",
            sphericalMercator: true
            },
            {isBaseLayer: true}
        );

        var trains_stations = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Gares (geojson)", {
                styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    pointRadius: 15,
                    fillColor: "#ffcc66",
                    fillOpacity: 0.8,
                   strokeColor: "#cc6633",
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8 } ),
                    "select": { fillColor: "#8aeeef",
                    strokeColor: "#32a8a9",
                    labelYOffset:13,
                    label:"${NOM}"} //Text entspricht feature.attributes.name
               }),
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "gares.geojson",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
               })
          });

        var trains = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Trains (geojson)", {
            projection: "EPSG:4326",
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "trains.geojson",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
        });

  map.addLayers([mblight, trains_stations, trains]);
  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );
  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-8198217,5701810));
  map.zoomTo(12);

}

</script>
```

Both files, trains and gares.geojson are in the same folders as my HTML.

This is an extract from `gares.geojson` (in case the problem's there):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", 
"properties": { "NO_STATION": 101.0, "NOM": "Gare Lucien-L'Allier", "NoAbord08": 18, "Parking": 0 }, 
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.570806, 45.494761 ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", 
"properties": { "NO_STATION": 214.0, "NOM": "Gare Delson", "NoAbord08": 41, "Parking": 1 }, 
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.540803, 45.366832 ] } }

]
}
```

I literally copy paste those two recipes and only changed the data source.

Comment: I've put a copy of mt data in my public Dropbox folder and used it as my source and it worked... The example I saw used the http protocol, but the data was local too... I don't understand...

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: No, it's just not showing on my map...

Comment: are you using firebug?

Comment: I installed it and I'm not seeing anything wrong. I must not know what to look.

Comment: check the net tab, refresh your page with F5 and then things will appear. Normally look at those in the end, things in red are most of the time indicative of things failing.

Comment: GET gares.geojson 404 Not Found 33ms

Comment: Can you show where you have placed the two files and your html and js files in your website? What happens if you directly call the geojson file by url in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the demo! After checking it, I found two problems in the "Trains" section, I solved your problem, so please find it here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/Gery/xf62Z/2/

Below I will keep my previous answer, but I consider that the JSFIDDLE link above will solve your problem.

--

Since the error points to the "*.geojson" file and says "Not Found", try making it executable with (for linux):

```
chmod a+x gares.geojson trains.geojson
```

since you use windows, the similar concept is known as "full control" access:

> - Use Windows Explorer to navigate to the file or directory.
> - Right click on it, and select Properties.
> - Select the Security tab.
> - Click the Add button.
> - Use the dialogue to grant Full Control to "Everyone".

and then add "./" to the URL in the protocol like:

```
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
     url: "./gares.geojson",
     format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
})
```

and

```
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
     url: "./trains.geojson",
     format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
})
```

I tested the extract of your gares.geojson in http://geojsonlint.com/ and works well:

[image]

In case you need to follow [a working example](http://gis-lab.info/share/DR/sandbox/geojson.html) using [geojson](http://gis-lab.info/share/DR/sandbox/data/l1.geojson), here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lon = 90,
            lat = 60,
            zoom = 3,
            epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
            epsg900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');

        function init(){
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
                units: 'm',
                numZoomLevels: 19,
                controls: [
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
                ],
                projection: epsg900913,
                displayProjection: epsg4326 //Is used for displaying coordinates in appropriate CRS by MousePosition control
            });

            var lay_goo = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google', {
                type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                sphericalMercator: true
            });

            var lay_osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('OSM');

            geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
                projection: epsg4326,
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "./data/l1.geojson",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                })
            });

            map.addLayers([lay_osm, lay_goo, geojson_layer]);

            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(epsg4326, epsg900913), zoom);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="map" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Still no luck. I'm on windows so I gave everybody full control, but I don't know if that makes it executable?

Comment: I'd say probably, please check the update in my answer. Btw, try putting the *.geojson files in a new directory, something like `url: "./data/trains.geojson"`

Comment: They were initially in a different folder. I thought I was referencing them wrong so I moved them in the same folder as my index.html. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it's still not working. I grand full control to Everyone. Even tried to copy/paste your code and it's working with the file on my Dropbox account. Frustrating and thanks a million times for your help.

Comment: mmm, I'm wondering if the `var mblight = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ` call you have is the problematic one, comment it and see if that worked. I'd be cool if you can make a live demo so it'll be easier for me to investigate what's going on

Comment: Thanks! http://www.fgcartographix.com/temp/cartis/ol.html or http://www.fgcartographix.com/temp/cartis.zip  Much appreciated.

Comment: @fgcartographix you're welcome, I solved it, please check my updated answer, mark it as the answer if you considered as such and upvote it if you find it useful =), cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I would have accepted your first answer in any case because it was obviously working... ;) Thanks again!!

Comment: @fgcartographix you're welcome! glad to help! =)